# How to remove a Button "shadow" in CSS

Tags: css, button, shadow

I have a simple question. I've created a button with css properties, but if I use button:active and try to animate something doesn't matter what I get some annoying kind of "shadows" top and left in my button. How can I delete them? I am new to Stack Overflow i hope I do not do anything wrong here :)

```css
button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.3s;
  background-color: white;
  border-width: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: grey;
  border-color: rgb(70, 196, 255);
  box-shadow: none;
}

button:hover {
  border-left-width: 5px;
}

button:active {
  border-color: rgb(123, 20, 80);
}

button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button></button>
</body>
```

Comment: If I press the button the left border should get kind of purple but instead it gets nearly black. That is what i meant with a "shadow".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button was still using the default border styling; you can fix this by adding `border-style: solid`

```
button:active {
  border-color: rgb(123, 20, 80);
  border-style: solid
}
```

It might be easier for you to then use the Shorthand version [`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border) to defined the Width, Style, and Color all in the same line

```css
button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.3s;
  background-color: white;
  border-width: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: grey;
  border-color: rgb(70, 196, 255);
  box-shadow: none;
}

button:hover {
  border-left-width: 5px;
}

button:active {
  border-color: rgb(123, 20, 80);
  border-style: solid;
}

button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button></button>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! :) Yeah you are right with the border command, but I think it got a habit to use a bit more code for the same result.